# Sleeping mode on Android

Tags: android, sleep-mode

My question is, what is the API for the sleep mode of a phone, if the phone is not used for a couple of minutes it goes into sleep mode right? Well what is the programming section on Android development is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) and its inner class [PowerManager.WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html).
For example, to prevent some code from sleeping wrap it with

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) SJPhone.getContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(flags,WAKE_LOCK_STR);
wl.acquire();

// you code goes here

wl.release();
wl = null;
```